# Changing doze mode setting using adb

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

From what I learned from this source code of [Doze Editor app](https://github.com/p0isonra1n/Doze-Settings-Editor/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/isaacparker/dozesettingseditor/MainActivity.java) it is possible to change the doze settings using adb.

My question, can I change only one setting at a time?

for example:

```
adb shell settings put global device_idle_constants KEY_INACTIVE_TIMEOUT=720000
```

Or should I put all the value-pairs separated by comma?

for example:

```
adb shell settings put global device_idle_constants KEY_INACTIVE_TIMEOUT=720000, KEY_SENSING_TIMEOUT=xxxx, KEY_LOCATING_TIMEOUT=yyyy ... and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I change only one setting at a time?

Yes, you can't change multiple settings at once.

The command `adb shell settings` only supports one key/value at a time, as you can see in the command help:

```
adb shell settings
usage:  settings [--user NUM] get namespace key
        settings [--user NUM] put namespace key value
        settings [--user NUM] delete namespace key

'namespace' is one of {system, secure, global}, case-insensitive
If '--user NUM' is not given, the operations are performed on the owner user.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to official comments in Android SDK, you need to put all the value-pairs under the key "device_idle_constants", example:
    "inactive_timeout=60000,sensing_timeout=400000"